# Loading previously stored data from SharedPreferences into PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, fragment, settings, preferences

I've followed the documentation to create a Preference Fragment. All of my preferences are working as expected, but I have a first and last name setting that I'd like to load dynamically from SharedPreferences. These values have already been stored when the user logged in.

Their values in strings.xml:

```
 <string name="first_name">first_name</string>
 <string name="last_name">last_name</string>
```

Them being saved on login:

```
editor.putString(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.first_name), firstName);
editor.putString(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.last_name), lastName);
editor.commit();
```

The preferences in preferences.xml:

```
   <EditTextPreference
                android:key="@string/first_name"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:persistent="true"
                android:title="First Name"/>
    <EditTextPreference
                android:key="@string/last_name"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:persistent="true"
                android:title="Last Name"/>
```

Trying to load them in Preference Fragment:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sessionManager = SessionManager.getInstance(getActivity());
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getActivity(), R.xml.preferences, false);

        // Set first and last name preference default values
        firstNamePreference = (EditTextPreference)findPreference("first_name");
        lastNamePreference = (EditTextPreference)findPreference("last_name");
        nearbyPreference = (CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("show_places");
//        firstNamePreference.setText(sessionManager.getUserFirstName());
//        firstNamePreference.setSummary(sessionManager.getUserFirstName());
//        lastNamePreference.setText(sessionManager.getUserLastName());
//        lastNamePreference.setSummary(sessionManager.getUserLastName());
        nearbyPreference.setDefaultValue(true);
    }
```

So I can set them manually (as well as the summary), but I'd really like to set them from the already set values in SharedPreferences. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after looking through my code, I realized that my application stores preferences in a file other than the default. So, I had to do the following from [this](http://codetheory.in/saving-user-settings-with-android-preferences/) article:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getActivity(), R.xml.preferences, false);


        sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("file_name", 0); // 0 is private

        // show the current value in the settings screen
        for (int i = 0; i < getPreferenceScreen().getPreferenceCount(); i++) {
            pickPreferenceObject(getPreferenceScreen().getPreference(i));
        }
    }

private void pickPreferenceObject(Preference p) {
        if (p instanceof PreferenceCategory) {
            PreferenceCategory cat = (PreferenceCategory) p;
            for (int i = 0; i < cat.getPreferenceCount(); i++) {
                pickPreferenceObject(cat.getPreference(i));
            }
        } else {
            initSummary(p);
        }
    }

private void initSummary(Preference p) {
        if (p instanceof EditTextPreference) {
            EditTextPreference editTextPref = (EditTextPreference) p;
            String value = sharedPreferences.getString(editTextPref.getKey(), "");
            p.setSummary(value);
            ((EditTextPreference) p).setText(value);
        }
        // More logic for ListPreference, etc...
    }
```

Otherwise you could probably just set them each with the default prefs, accessed like so:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
```

Comment: This whole thing is such a joke. Android does it again, how wonderful

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is what you should be looking at doing:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    // Sets the first name based on the SharedPreference value
    Preference pref = getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("first_name");
    pref.setSummary(pref.getSharedPreferences().getString("first_name", "default value if first_name key not set"));

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me :( @michaelcarrano